# Element with absolute position inside Iframe possible?

Tags: iframe

I need to give an element absolute position inside an iframe so it scrolls up and down with it.

This is my iframe:

```
<iframe  scrolling="yes" onload="initTimer();" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" src="http://chusmix.com;?>" style="position: absolute; background-color: transparent; width: 100%; height:100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; z-index: 1; left: 0;">
</iframe>
```

If it's not possible maybe there is a way to know how much the iframe has been scrolled and reposition elements acordingly. Anyhow any ideas are welcomed. Thanks